# Regexp help: why does this output include duplicates?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string: `remove_names = "Jimmy X" <jimmy@x1.com>, "jimmy@x2.com <jimmy@x2.com>, "spitfire672@x3.com" <spitfire672@x3.com>`

I'm trying to extract the email addresses with

```
emailsArray = remove_names.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
```

This makes emailsArray `[jimmy@x1.com,jimmy@x2.com,jimmy@x2.com,spitfire672@x3.com,spitfire672@x3.com]`

Which obviously has duplicates.

I think I need to change the regexp argument to `match(...)` such that the results doesn't include duplicates (i.e. scan for the `< >`). I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that anything between the `<` and `>` is a valid email, it's easiest to match on that and ignore the other text. `/<([^>]+)>/g` will find all the text inside the `<>` brackets. You could then remove the brackets themselves by getting a substring without the first and last characters, or use the $1 capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that this is [not quite a valid email regular expression...](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

You're missing the angle brackets around your regex:

```
/<([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)>/
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. this gives: "<email1@gmail.com>,email1@gmail.com" and discards the other emails.

Answer (score 1):

It's not matching duplicates.  The first `jimmy@x2.com` is the overall match, and the second `jimmy@x2.com` is the contents of the first capturing group.  Lose the parentheses and it should work as you intended.